# Integral changes variable subscripts

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have been away from Mathematica for quite a while and am trying to fix some old notebooks from v4 that are no longer working under v11.  I'm also a tad rusty.

I am attempting to use functional minimization to fit a polynomial of variable degree to an arbitrary function (F) given a starting guess (ao) and domain of interest (d).  Note that while F is arbitrary, its nature is such that the integral of the product of F and a polynomial (or F^2) can always be evaluated algebraically.

For the sake of example, I'll use the following inputs:

```
ao = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
d = { -1, 1 }
F = Sin[x]
```

To do so, I create an array of 'indexed' variables

```
polyCoeff = Array[a,Length[a],0]
```

> Result: polycoeff = {a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]}

I then create the polynomial itself using the following

```
genPoly[{},x_] := 0
genPoly[a_List,x_] := First[a] + x genPoly[Rest[a],x]
poly = genPoly[polyCoeff,x]
```

> Result: poly = a[0] + x (a[1] + x (a[2] + x a[3]))

I then define my objective function as the integral of the square of the error of the difference between this poly and the function I am attempting to fit:

```
Q = Integrate[ (poly - F[x])^2, {x, d[[1]],d[[2]]} ]
```

> result: Q = 0.545351 - 2. a[0.]^2 + 0.66667 a[1.]^2 + .....

And this is where things break down.  poly looks just as I expected: a polynomial in x with coefficients that look like a[0], a[1], a[2], ...   But, Q is not exactly what I expected.  I expected and got a new polynomial.  But not the coefficients contained a[0.], a[1.], a[2.], ...

The next step is to create the initial guess for FindMinimum

```
init = Transpose[{polyCoeff,ao}]
```

> Result: {{a[0],1},{a[1],2},{a[3],3},{a[4],4}}

This looks fine.

But when I make the call to FindMinimum, I get an error because the coefficients passed in the objective (a[0.],a[1.],...) do not match those passed in the initial guess (a[0],a[1],...).

```
S = FindMinimum[Q,init]
```

So I **think** my question is how do I keep Integrate from changing the arguments to my coefficients?  But, I am open to other approaches as well.  Keep in mind though that this is "legacy" work that I really don't want to have to completely revamp.

Thanks much for any/all help.

Comment: Try https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Is there a decimal point anywhere in the definition of your function F? Any decimal point might be responsible for turning your integers into decimal approximations. If you could provide the simplest possible complete code then I might be able to reproduce your problem or spot the source of the problem.

Comment: When I copied the code over to SO, I missed the fact that the limits of integration contained a decimal point:  d = {-1.,1.};  But I'm still confused why that would modify the fixed scalar value being passed as the arguments to the a-coefficients.  I guess once a floating point value is introduced, all numbers are translated to floating point regardless of whether or not there is a need to do so?

Comment: Ah. My guess was likely correct. If you imagine adding EXACTLY 1/2 and EXACTLY 1/3 you might expect to get EXACTLY 5/6. A decimal point tells MMA that 0.5 is APPROXIMATELY a half and calculating almost any result with an approximate number, even when it contains other exact numbers, will give an approximate result. So. Do your problems persist if you eliminate all approximate values in your calculation and restart MMA and then redo the calculations?